# Install Zoho CRM SDK (or any SDK for that matter)

Tags: error-message, composer, services

For a client I need to connect a rather complex contact form with the Zoho CRM. They're offering a [PHP SDK](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/developer/server-side-sdks/php.html) which sounds great, but I can't get it to work. It's very likely that I'm just stupid, because I can't even include the SDK to just call the initial setup method.

The documentation says (under "Using the PHP SDK") to include the following line where needed:

```
require ‘vendor/autoload.php’
```

That doesn't seem to be needed, as it's already done in the main **index.php** by Craft itself.

I want to use the SDK within a service class I've created under **modules/services**. So within my class I tried the following:

```
require "../vendor/zohocrm/php-sdk/src/index.php";
```

That's getting the the **index.php** from the SDK but when I'm calling the method `ZCRMRestClient::initialize()` I just get the following error message:

> Class 'modules\services\ZCRMRestClient' not found

I'm probably missing some really basic stuff but I just don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got Composer installed from the [command line](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx), you can navigate to your project's root (where your project's composer.json file lives), then run this from the command line:

```
composer require zohocrm/php-sdk
```

From there, Composer and Craft pretty much take care of everything, including setting up the autoloading and you can reference `ZCRMRestClient::initialize();` from your module/service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure I tried it, but in the end the problem was that I tried calling it as `ZCRMRestClient::initialize();` and not as `\ZCRMRestClient::initialize();˚, so with a slash at the beginning. I also tried `use ZCRMRestClient` and then calling it without the slash, but that didn't work — maybe I should learn a bit more about the `use` statement ;-)